# Why does NPM install another node_modules folder within a polymer element and how can this be fixed?

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit, polymer-3.x

## Question

I am following the "Build an App with App Toolbox" tutorial. I had an issue with step 3 "add some elements" where the view would not display once I try to add the `paper-checkbox` element.

After some trial and error, I discovered that there is an extra `node_modules` folder within the `paper-checkbox` folder. This caused the view to break and therefore not display (more on this below). Why does this happen and how can this be fixed?

**Tutorial Link**

https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/start/toolbox/add-elements

## Full Problem Details

I started the project using the command line interface, ran `polymer init` and chose `polymer-3-starter-kit` per the tutorial instructions. I ran the following command to install `paper-checkbox`:

```
npm install @polymer/paper-checkbox
```

Note that I get the following warning after I install the element:

```
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-classes@7.0.0-beta.35 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.35 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ @polymer/paper-checkbox@3.0.0-pre.20
added 12 packages from 1 contributor and audited 13720 packages in 27.422s
found 46 vulnerabilities (25 low, 14 moderate, 5 high, 2 critical)
run npm audit fix to fix them, or npm audit for details
```

I checked my `node_modules` folder and I can see that `paper-checkbox` was installed.

So far when I load `my-new-view` it displays correctly, like this:
[image]

However, when I add the import statement inside `my-new-view.js` for the `paper-checkbox` element,
`import '@polymer/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.js';` the view fails to display:

[image]

After some code comparison with another project, I see that the `paper-checkbox` folder does not match up (see screenshot below). It contains a duplicate `node_modules` folder, which contains a duplicate `@polymer` folder. This polymer folder contains `font-robota` and other modules that are already contained in the top polymer directory; even more duplicated content.

[image]

Furthermore, on inspecting the webpage, the console (on chrome) gives the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this registry at Polymer (http://127.0.0.1:8081/node_modules/@polymer/polymer/lib/legacy/polymer-fn.js:43:18)
at http://127.0.0.1:8081/node_modules/@polymer/paper-checkbox/node_modules/@polymer/iron-meta/iron-meta.js:141:1
```

This error occurs due to the fact that there is duplicate content. To solve this, I simply deleted the `node_modules` folder within the checkbox element.

I also tried installing `paper-input` as well. `paper-input` requires `iron-input`. After running `npm install @polymer/paper-input` the same `node_modules` folder is installed within both the iron and paper input elements. I deleted these two folders and then the element finally works.

Why does npm do this? And how can I fix it?

**Github Project Repo**

https://github.com/starkindustries/my-first-polymer-app

**Version Info**

- Git Version 2.17.1 (Apple Git-112)
- NPM version 6.4.1
- Node version v10.10.0
- Polymer CLI version 1.8.0
- Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `npm install @polymer/paper-checkbox` from the project root? If you run `npm install` command from the root of `papaer-checkbox` folder, it would read it's dependency folder from it's package.json file and install them.

Comment: Yes, I did run the command from the project root and still the extra node_modules folder is installed.